# Upgrade magento2.3.0 to 2.4.1- allowed memory error

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.0, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.1, composer-update

I followed below steps:
Part 1:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento cache:disable
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.1 --no-update
composer update
```

After composer update, got error message[image]

I added **memory limit=-1** in `php.ini` file.

Please advise.

Comment: May be you can try ini_set('memory_limit', '80M');

Answer (score 0):

added memory_limit=2048m

error resolved.